# SSL Traffic Inspection

Tags: encryption, tls

Is the firewall decrypted my session? There is an error "Certificate Not Trusted" (Server Certificate changed to Firewall Cyberoam Certificate). Which public Key I got? Is Main server Public Key or Cyberoam Public Key? Is SSL traffic inspection is same for Authenticated Encryption "GCM" ?

[image: My Firewall Blocks and it is a snapshot of SSL]

Comment: Click on _Certificate information_ to see the information of the certificate. Most likely, it is self-signed or signed by a CA that is not trusted. In any case, **do not exchange sensitive information on that website until the problem is corrected**. That includes, but is not limited to passwords and contact information. If possible, notify the admin of the domain so he can take measures about it.

Comment: This isn't really crypto per se and fits better on security.SE, where it is a dupe: start with http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8145/does-https-prevent-man-in-the-middle-attacks-by-proxy-server and http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19616/why-is-it-possible-to-sniff-an-https-ssl-request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the firewall decrypted my session?

In order to inspect the encrypted traffic, your firewall has to decrypt it firts, one way, or the other. Since it can't do it any other way, it "impersonates you/your computer" as the client to the server (and creates an encrypted connection to the server) and also "impersonates the server" to your computer as the client (and creates an encrypted connection with you).

> There is an error "Certificate Not Trusted" (Server Certificate changed to Firewall Cyberoam Certificate).

That's because the firewall has to "impersonate" the server to your client and as it can not use the real servers certificate for authentication/en/decryption/data integrity of the traffic between you (as the client) and it (as the server), it has to use its own. The certificate the firewall uses is issued by its own CA that's obviously not set as trusted in your browser.

> Which public Key I got? Is Main server Public Key or Cyberoam Public Key?

The firewalls (Cyberoam).

> Is SSL traffic inspection is same for Authenticated Encryption "GCM" ?

AFAIK, yes.

The only problem I see here is if you don't know your encrypted traffic is being inspected / don't want it inspected. If you do, you should set the firewalls CA as trusted in your browser and that'd be that. Here are the instructions from [Cyberoam Knowledge Base](https://kb.cyberoam.com/default.asp?id=2339)

Hope I helped.